# Github Action: No signing certificate "iOS Development" found

Tags: ios, xcode, github, app-store, github-actions

The related issue is here: https://github.com/yukiarrr/ios-build-action/issues/74

UPDATE: there is no "iOS Development" inside any of the code in my project. And that word only shows when I put a string rather than GitHub secret on the `code-signing-identity`, regardless of what string I input.

I was using `ios-build-action@v1.5.0` on Github Action to automate the process of deploying my Ionic project to TestFlight. But somehow I ran into this error.

The new provisioning profile has been generated and provided as a secret, and I believe the certificate is also generated during the build process.

Is there any solution for this? What could be the possible issues?

The related commend:

```
      - name: Publish as internal testing
        uses: yukiarrr/ios-build-action@v1.5.0
        with:
          project-path: ./platforms/ios/myproject.xcodeproj
          p12-base64: ${{ secrets.IOS_P12_BASE64 }}
          mobileprovision-base64: ${{ secrets.IOS_PROVISION_FILE }}
          code-signing-identity: Apple Development
          team-id: ${{ secrets.IOS_TEAM_ID }}
```

The related log is given below, which is slightly different from that issue:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|                                           Summary for gym 2.205.2                                            |
+--------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| workspace                                        | ./platforms/ios/myproject.xcworkspace                      |
| configuration                                    | Release                                                   |
| scheme                                           | myproject                                                  |
| output_directory                                 | .                                                         |
| output_name                                      | output                                                    |
| clean                                            | true                                                      |
| export_method                                    | app-store                                                 |
| export_options.provisioningProfiles.com.myproject | myproject Github Action CI/CD                              |
| skip_profile_detection                           | false                                                     |
| destination                                      | generic/platform=iOS                                      |
| silent                                           | false                                                     |
| skip_package_ipa                                 | false                                                     |
| skip_package_pkg                                 | false                                                     |
| build_path                                       | /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2022-04-28 |
| result_bundle                                    | false                                                     |
| buildlog_path                                    | ~/Library/Logs/gym                                        |
| xcodebuild_formatter                             | xcpretty                                                  |
| xcodebuild_command                               | xcodebuild                                                |
| skip_package_dependencies_resolution             | false                                                     |
| disable_package_automatic_updates                | false                                                     |
| use_system_scm                                   | false                                                     |
| xcode_path                                       | /Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app                            |
+--------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
[22:27:00]: $ set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace ./platforms/ios/myproject.xcworkspace -scheme myproject -configuration Release -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2022-04-28/output\ 2022-04-28\ 22.27.00.xcarchive clean archive | tee /Users/runner/Library/Logs/gym/myproject-myproject.log | xcpretty
[22:27:06]: ▸ Clean Succeeded
[22:27:13]: ▸ ❌  error: No signing certificate "iOS Development" found: No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "***" with a private key was found. (in target 'myproject' from project 'myproject')
[22:27:13]: ▸ ❌  error: Provisioning profile "myproject Github Action CI/CD" doesn't support the Push Notifications capability. (in target 'myproject' from project 'myproject')
[22:27:13]: ▸ ❌  error: Provisioning profile "myproject Github Action CI/CD" doesn't include the aps-environment entitlement. (in target 'myproject' from project 'myproject')
[22:27:13]: ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
▸ Clean Succeeded
❌  error: No certificate for team '***' matching '***' found: Select a different signing certificate for CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY, a team that matches your selected certificate, or switch to automatic provisioning. (in target 'myproject' from project 'myproject')
❌  error: Provisioning profile "myproject Github Action CI/CD" doesn't support the Push Notifications capability. (in target 'myproject' from project 'myproject')
❌  error: Provisioning profile "myproject Github Action CI/CD" doesn't include the aps-environment entitlement. (in target 'myproject' from project 'myproject')
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[22:27:13]: Exit status: 65
[22:27:13]: 
[22:27:13]: Maybe the error shown is caused by using the wrong version of Xcode
[22:27:13]: Found multiple versions of Xcode in '/Applications/'
[22:27:13]: Make sure you selected the right version for your project
[22:27:13]: This build process was executed using '/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app'
[22:27:13]: If you want to update your Xcode path, either
[22:27:13]: 
[22:27:13]: - Specify the Xcode version in your Fastfile
[22:27:13]: ▸ xcversion(version: "8.1") # Selects Xcode 8.1.0
[22:27:13]: 
[22:27:13]: - Specify an absolute path to your Xcode installation in your Fastfile
[22:27:13]: ▸ xcode_select "/Applications/Xcode8.app"
[22:27:13]: 
[22:27:13]: - Manually update the path using
[22:27:13]: ▸ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
[22:27:13]: 
+---------------+--------------------------------+
|               Build environment                |
+---------------+--------------------------------+
| xcode_path    | /Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app |
| gym_version   | 2.205.2                        |
| export_method | app-store                      |
| sdk           | iPhoneOS15.2.sdk               |
+---------------+--------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was caused by having different app id on iOS and Android but didn't separate them in the `config.xml`. If you encounter the issue, you may want to check your app id to see if they are consistent on different platforms. In my case, iOS app id wasn't applied correctly causing this issue.